# Call multiple API using rxjs and return it as obserable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having 4 API let be A,B,C,D and I want to get combine data of all 4 API into single obserable.

I want using `forkJoin([A,B])` and using the response of forkJoin into `forkJoin([C,D])`.
Example:

```
return forJoin([a,b]).pipe(map result=>{
 return forkJoin([c(a.result),d(a.result,b.result)]);
})
```

Problem for is that I am only getting C and D API response.
Anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there should be a `switchMap` for returning the inner `forkJoin`. And if you want to return also the `a` and `b` response, you can just use `of` the original result:

```
return forkJoin([a,b]).pipe(
  switchMap(result => {
    return forkJoin([c(result[0]),d(result[0], result[1]), of(result)]
  })
})
```

Now you get an array of all 3 results, last beeing the array of the first response